# Reading data from files into tables using hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

In HDFS I have amount of files and folders. I want to read data from files into tables using Apache Hive.
I use the following code if the corresponding piece of data lies in folder:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IPRegions (
    -- some fields
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    -- regexp
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/data/user_logs/ipdata_folder'; --this is a path to the folder with data
```

**How should I change this code** (I think, only last 2 strings will be changed) **if the corresponding piece of data lies in a single file?**

P.S. I don't have permissions to create new folders and move files in HDFS.

UPD. Briefly, my code works well only if the datasource is **folder** (for example `/data/user_logs/ipdata_folder`). But if I want to work with a single file (for example `/data/user_logs/ipdata_folder/logS.txt`), I catch an error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:hdfs://bds11.vdi.mipt.ru:8020/data/user_logs/user_logs_S/logS.txt is not a directory or unable to create one)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem more clearly? I am not getting anything.

Comment: Yes. Briefly, my code works well only if the datasource is folder (for example `/data/user_logs/ipdata_folder`). But if I want to work with a single file (for example `/data/user_logs/ipdata_folder/logS.txt`), I catch an error: `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:hdfs://bds11.vdi.mipt.ru:8020/data/user_logs/user_logs_S/logS.txt is not a directory or unable to create one)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive tables work at folder level, so you cannot specify a file as a valid location.

Being said that, if you have more than a file within `/data/user_logs/ipdata_folder` and you only want to add to the table the data within a specific file (ignoring the others), then you'll need to copy such a file into another folder and specify that alternative folder as the location in the table definition.

Nevertheless, you say you don't have permissions to create folders nor moving files. That is strongly limitating... So, the only thing I think you can do is to maintain the table definition as it is, which means all the data files will be added to the table, and perform some kind of filtering on the data when querying for it.